# Specifying varnish's default virtual-host

Tags: varnish

I'm using Varnish-3.0.5 on Scientific Linux 6.4 (64bit):

```
$ rpm -q varnish
varnish-3.0.5-1.el5.centos.x86_64
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Scientific Linux release 6.4 (Carbon)
$ uname -a
Linux XXX.XXX.XXX 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 16 11:13:47 CDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ curl XXX.XX.XX.XXX

<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Unavailable</title>
  <style>
    body { background: #303030; text-align: center; color: white; }
    #page { border: 1px solid #CCC; width: 500px; margin: 100px auto 0; padding: 30px; background: #323232; }
    a, a:link, a:visited { color: #CCC; }
    .error { color: #222; }
  </style>
</head>
<body onload="setTimeout(function() { window.location = '/' }, 5000)">
  <div id="page">
    <h1 class="title">Page Unavailable</h1>
    <p>The page you requested is temporarily unavailable.</p>
    <p>We're redirecting you to the <a href="/">homepage</a> in 5 seconds.</p>
    <div class="error">(Error 503 Service Unavailable)</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
$
```

I trying to figure out how I can configure default virtual-host as I'm getting `Error 503 Service Unavailable` if at least one of my back-end(s) is down whenever I run `curl` against IP address. Do I need to specify IP address in `req.http.host` as well inside of `vcl_recv()` in order for me to stop getting 503? or how else do I specify which virtual-host is default?

Comment: So you want Varnish to not serve the response to the client (and instead try another backend) if it gets that 503 response from the backend, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all let me say that it's quite difficult to give advices without seen your actual VCL config.

**To respond your actual question**

You can set a default host at the beginning of your `vcl_recv`, note that your backend(s) should be configured to respond to that exact host

```
sub vcl_recv {
  /* set a default host if no host is provided on the request or if it is empty */
  if ( ! req.http.host 
    || req.http.host == "") {
    set req.http.host = "your.default.host.tld";
  }
  # ...

}
```

I think you don't have to mess with IPs and `req.http.host`, you should better use curl to pass a host header to varnish (something like `curl -H "Host: your.default.host.tld" http://XX.XX.XX.XXX/`)

---

**Some general suggestions on the topic:**

Add misbehaving control logic to your VCL [1]

***Are you setting your backend correctly?***

Remember that varnish will uses "default" backend (or director) unless instructed to use other on your VCl logic

***Add health probes and see what backends are failing***

Use consistent health probes [2] and use commandline command `varnishadm debug.health` see the docs for a better understanding [3]

***Add a restart logic to your vlc error***

Something like this

```
sub vcl_error {
  # ...

  /* Try to restart request in case of failure */
  if (obj.status == 503 && req.restarts < 5) {
    set obj.http.X-Restarts = req.restarts;
    return(restart);
  }

  # Before any deliver
  return (deliver);
}
```

***Add debug logic to your vlc error synthetic response***

Remember that you can add debug headers on `vcl_fetch` passing backend error code to your varnish error response:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
  # ...

  set beresp.http.X-Debug-Backend-Code = beresp.status;

  # ...
}
sub vcl_error {
  # ...

  synthetic {""
  # Insert the following at the end of your current response
  <p>Backend Status code was "} + obj.http.X-Debug-Backend-Code + {"</p>
    </body>
  </html>
  "};

  # ...

  return (deliver);
}
```

[1] https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/handling_misbehaving_servers.html

[2] https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html#backend-probes

[3] https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/BackendPolling#CLIcommands